# Iphone screen black on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an iPhone app and incorporating parse. Originally, a starter project from Parse.com. This file used xib instead of storyboard; I deleted xib and made my own storyboard, and changed to Main storyboard file name base: Main_iPhone in my info.plist file. And then I dragged out a view controller and set the little arrow pointing to that view controller, but the screen is just black when the application launches. What is happening?
Here my ap delegate code:

```
//
//  ParseStarterProjectAppDelegate.m
//  ParseStarterProject
//
//  Copyright 2014 Parse, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Parse/Parse.h>

// If you want to use any of the UI components, uncomment this line
// #import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>

// If you are using Facebook, uncomment this line
// #import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>

// If you want to use Crash Reporting - uncomment this line
// #import <ParseCrashReporting/ParseCrashReporting.h>

#import "ParseStarterProjectAppDelegate.h"


@implementation ParseStarterProjectAppDelegate

#pragma mark - UIApplicationDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"  bundle:nil];

    // Instantiate the initial view controller object from the storyboard
    //self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore. Remove this line if you don't want to
    // use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];

    // ****************************************************************************
    // Uncomment this line if you want to enable Crash Reporting
    // [ParseCrashReporting enable];
    //
    // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:
     [Parse setApplicationId:@"privatecrap" clientKey:@"privatecrap"];
    //
    // If you are using Facebook, uncomment and add your FacebookAppID to your bundle's plist as
    // described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/
    // [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
    // ****************************************************************************

    [PFUser enableAutomaticUser];

    PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    [defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];

    [PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    //[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.
        BOOL preBackgroundPush = ![application respondsToSelector:@selector(backgroundRefreshStatus)];
        BOOL oldPushHandlerOnly = ![self respondsToSelector:@selector(application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)];
        BOOL noPushPayload = ![launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
        }
    }

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 80000
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                                 categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    } else
#endif
    {
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }



//    self.window.rootViewController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"emailStoryboard"];

    return YES;
}

/*

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Uncomment this method if you are using Facebook
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [PFFacebookUtils handleOpenURL:url];
}

 */

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
    [PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken];
    [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@"" target:self selector:@selector(subscribeFinished:error:)];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error.code == 3010) {
        NSLog(@"Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.");
    } else {
        // show some alert or otherwise handle the failure to register.
        NSLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Uncomment this method if you want to use Push Notifications with Background App Refresh
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
    }
}
 */

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state.
     This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message)
     or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates.
     Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state
     information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
     If your application supports background execution,
     this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}

#pragma mark - ()

- (void)subscribeFinished:(NSNumber *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if ([result boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click on your project in the file explorer on the left side, under general does "Main interface" contain the name of your storyboard?

[image]

Also you have said (I think), that your storyboard is call `Main_iPhone`, however your code is calling `Main` and then doing nothing with the storyboard or checking if its `nil` etc.

You either need to set the main interface in the target, or instantiate the initial `viewController` inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and set it as the rootViewController of the window. e.g.

```
self.window.rootViewController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil] instantiateInitialViewController];
```

you don't need to do both, only one or the other.

Comment: Yeah it's been confusing for me which is a better name by default, Main_iPhone Storyboard or Main Stoaryboard.